# Execute a command in bash script

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I'm trying to execute a command inside a shell script (in my case using `sh` as my shell) when the command is passed as the first argument to the shell script. Example:

```
sh command_execute.sh ls -l
```

Let's say I enter the above on the command line, ideally I would like the script to look at the first argument (which in this case would be `ls -l`), and execute it.

Comment: You are incorrect.  When you execute `sh command_execute.sh ls -l`, the first argument is *not* `ls -l`.  The first argument is `ls`, and the second argument is `-l`.

Comment: @Andrew : You are not running bash here, but sh. Also, the first argument in your example is `ls` and not `ls -l`. Also, I don't see how you intend _nano_ to be useful with your task. Please clarify.

Comment: @WilliamPursell and @ the other person replying, I'm sorry that this question was worded poorly. I am just learning all of this and I'm trying to learn more and I obviously still don't know what I am talking about quite yet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this. One way would be to set your shell script as

```
# File: command_execute.sh
$1
```

and run it like this: `sh command_execute.sh 'ls -l'` (notice the single quotes around `ls -l`). What this will do is the full string `ls -l` will be passed to your script, and since it is the first argument to the script, `$1` in the script will be effectively replaced with `ls -l`, and then that command will be executed.

The other way would be to use this as your script:

```
# File: command_execute.sh
"$@"
```

In this case, `"$@"` is all the arguments that were passed to the script. If you run the script like `sh command_execute.sh ls -l` (note in this case the `ls -l` is *not* quoted), then `ls` is passed to the script as argument 1, and `-l` is passed to the script as argument 2. Then `"$@"` is effectively replaced with `ls -l`, and then the command is executed.

Which of these is best depends on your requirements.

Comment: Definitely do the second, not the first. The quoted `"$@"` will preserve whitespace and globbing characters in the arguments.